# Как подружить approx (кэширующий прокси) и rpm?

Tags: linux, сеть, proxy, deb, rpm

Для deb-based дистрибутивов есть кэширующий прокси [`approx`](https://archive.debian.net/ru/squeeze/approx). Все пакеты, которые скачиваются через него (адрес сервера на конечных машинах надо поменять на тот, где этот аппрокс стоит) остаются и следующему клиенту отдаются уже из кэша со скоростью локалки.

Есть ли подобное для rpm-based? Выкачивать всё - как-то не улыбается.

Comment: для кэширования deb-пакетов есть ещё *apt-cacher* и *apt-cacher-ng*. а для rpm-пакетов ничего подобного, судя по всему, так и не написали: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/49297/equivalent-of-apt-cacher-for-rpmyum/

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, про ещё одни кэшелки деб-пакетов знаю. Просто именно аппрокс юзаем на работе - проблем нет. Жаль, что не написали. Оформи свой камент тогда в качестве ответа.

Comment: Хм, по ссылке есть адрес http://pulpproject.org/ . "Pulp can locally mirror all or part of a repository". Надо это поизучать, на сколько прозрачно будет работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

судя по вот этой информации *apt-cacher-ng* вполне можно использовать как минимум для кэширования пакетов из репозиториев для *redhat*-основных дистрибутивов:

- [apt-cacher-ng with CentOS](https://www.pitt-pladdy.com/blog/_20150720-132951_0100_Home_Lab_Project_apt-cacher-ng_with_CentOS/)
- [Caching CentOS packages on Ubuntu using apt-cacher-ng](https://askubuntu.com/q/250304/416190)
- [apt-cacher-ng and EL6 repos](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-cacher-ng/+bug/1006844)

возможно лишь потребуется дополнить паттерны (в зависимости от версии *apt-cacher-ng*).

Comment: Круто! Постараюсь потестить в ближайшее время.

Comment: кстати, и замена *approx* на *apt-cacher-ng*, насколько я понял, для клиентов вполне прозрачна, и не требует на их стороне никаких изменений.

Comment: Ну вроде как да. Главное пути после слэша те же оставить.